# Reading and Writing of Structure in C

Tags: c, structure

I'm trying to make a program that will let the user add, edit, view,load and save courses and compute their GWA(General Weighted Average). The only function that is not working is the loading/reading of courses!

so this is my structure:

```
struct studrec{     
    char crsnum[MAX_CNUM];
    char crstle[MAX_CTITLE];
    float grdobt;
    float crscrd;
};
```

and this is my function:

```
int loadCourses( struct studrec s[MAX_COURSES], int n ){

    FILE *fp=fopen("savedinputs.txt","r");
    int i;

    if(fp != NULL){
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &n);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            fscanf(fp, "%s \n", s[i].crsnum);
            fscanf(fp, "%s \n", s[i].crstle);
            fscanf(fp, "%f \n", &s[i].grdobt);
            fscanf(fp, "%f \n", &s[i].crscrd);
        }
        printf("Loaded!");
        fclose(fp);

    }
    else{
        printf("Error reading file");
    } 

    return n;
}
```

I don't know why but it causes SEGMENTATION FAULT.

This is how i called the load courses

```
main() {
//something working here

do{
    ch = dispMenu(ch);

    switch(ch){
        case 1: cnt = addCourse( crs  , cnt );
                break;
        case 2: editCourse( crs );
                break;
        case 3: searchCourse( crs );
                break;
        case 4: dispAllCourses( crs , cnt );
                break;
        case 5: computeGWA( crs );
                break;
        case 6: sortCourses( crs , cnt );
                break;
        case 7: cnt = loadCourses( crs , cnt ); //function call
                break;
        case 8: saveCourses( crs , cnt );
                break;
        case 0: printf("\n\tBye!\n");
                break;
        default: printf("\n\tInvalid Input!\n");
    }
}while(ch!=0);
```

}

The inputs are all correct (e.g. under the MAXCOURSES)

I moved the fclose(fp) but I have to say that s[i].crstle is a STRING WITH SPACES. How do I properly call them?

Comment: Show more code, i.e. how you call `loadCourses()`. Also make sure the `fopen()` succeeds, else `fp` is `NULL` which is not good for passing to `fscanf()`.

Comment: it is right before the first fscanf call the check for "NULL"

Comment: Run it with a debugger and you will see where it crashes

Comment: Why did you remove the code from your question ???

Answer (score 2):

`fclose(NULL)` is different from `free(NULL)`: Only the latter is specified as "do nothing".

`fclose(NULL)` is undefined behavior, and will explicitly crash on Microsoft's implementation of the C Standard Library. Therefore you should move your `fclose(fp);` call *inside* the `if`block.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the user can define a number of records higher than the available number of structs.

```
 struct studrec s[MAX_COURSES] //the struct defined
```

So you have to check that to check if the user input from:

```
 fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &n);
```

is not greater than MAX_COURSES